# [HTML]>> Basic form download input

Tags: html

So I would like to keep this very basic, I'd like this form:

```
<form>
-:
<input type="text" name="Username"><br>
-:
<input type="text" name="Email"><br>
-:
<input type="password" name="Password"><br>
-:
<input type="password" name="Re-Enter Password"><br>
-:
<input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
```

To use the input from the user after submit is pressed and download it into a log.txt file in the web files. I would like to then use that downloaded information, hash it then send it back to the web MANUALLY.

This will be a closed project I just would like some support on the subject, thanks.

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language. Step 2: Learn how to do server side programming with it.

Answer (score -2):

You can't store this anywhere, until using another language, that can do it.
For example: PHP.

Here's a place to start: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Also, you should close your form-tag.

And don't forget to sanitize whatever you get out of $_GET or $_POST or $_REQUEST, since this could potentially open up a lot of security-vulnerabilities, which would be very easy to exploit.

Comment: You should really start learning PHP, before trying to do this. Use the tutorials at w3schools and as reference you can use http://php.net